# How to make OpenApi UI work in Payara Micro

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, payara-micro

I have followed this tutorial [Swagger UI on MicroProfile OpenAPI](https://www.phillip-kruger.com/post/microprofile_openapi_swaggerui/) but simply adding the below to a pom.xml file of a Payara micro application does not add `/openapi-ui`, only `/openapi` works. Is there something else that is required or is it not possible with Payara Micro to have OpenApi UI.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.microprofile-ext.openapi-ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you try adding `<scope>runtime</scope>` as mentioned here: https://github.com/microprofile-extensions/openapi-ext/tree/master/openapi-ui Also, I guess you tried the URL `open-ui` (with lower case i)? You write it with an uppercase I.

Comment: The ui URL in the question was actually incorrect and I have corrected it. I have added the `<scope>runtime</scope>` and still no luck.

Comment: I assume you are using the most recent Payara Micro version?

Comment: Yes I am. Is that an issue?

Comment: No, just asking. Maybe something is fixed in newer version. Do you have, by chance, multiple applications deployed? Because OpenAPI will only be working for one (which is by design). See this issue on the Payara project: https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4470

Comment: Thanks. I did a little demo separately and it worked. So I had to apply what I did in the on the main project and I found my problem.

Comment: @FourtyTwo can I ask what you applied to the main project? I am having the same issue, but I'm not overriding any methods other than the constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the Application config class. I had to change

from:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/v1")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(MyResource.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

to

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {

}
```

Somehow overriding the `getClasses()` method and adding `/v1` to the application path was messing with the openApi-ui configurations.

Comment: If you find any explanation for this, please help me here [Add Swagger UI for Microprofile OpenAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396508/add-swagger-ui-for-microprofile-openapi)